# puppeteer fails in Docker and alpine linux with node with Error: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer, alpine-linux

I'm still getting this error. I see posts about back from 2018 and it still seems to be an issue.

`Error: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
import { Readability } from '@mozilla/readability';
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

let browser;

class Reader {
  async getLink(link) {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
      args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--single-process',
        '--no-zygote',
      ],
    });
    const htm = await spa(link);

    if (!htm) {
      await browser.close();
      return;
    }

    const text = txt(htm, link);
    const data = Object.assign({}, text);
    const parts = new URL(link);

    data.url = link;
    data.htm = htm;
    data.host = parts.host;
    data.text = data.textContent;
    delete data.textContent;

    console.log('data fetched: ' + link);
    await browser.close();
    // await browser.disconnect();

    return data;
  }
}


function txt(htm, link) {
  const url = new URL(link);
  const doc = new JSDOM(htm);
  doc.window.document
    .querySelectorAll('img')
    .forEach(
      (el) =>
        (el.src = el.src.indexOf('http') === 0 ? el.src : url.protocol + '//' + url.host + el.src),
    );
  doc.window.document
    .querySelectorAll('a[href]')
    .forEach(
      (el) =>
        (el.href = el.href.indexOf('/') === 0 ? url.protocol + '//' + url.host + el.href : el.href),
    );
  const reader = new Readability(doc.window.document);
  return reader.parse();
}

async function spa(url) {
  let htm;

  try {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 800, height: 600 });
    // await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    htm = await page.content();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err, url);
  }

  return htm;
}

export default Reader;
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-alpine

ENV CHROME_BIN="/usr/bin/chromium-browser"\
    PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD="true"

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
RUN apk add vim python python-dev py-pip build-base curl chromium htop ack
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install --production
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 8700
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```